# Is this 「より」used to make a comparison in this sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence

I have been trying to work on my Japanese particles for the past few days. I’m using a workbook titled “Japanese particle workbook” and I’m on it’s second usage of より where it says it’s the “indication of a comparison”,however; one of the sentences used as example doesn’t seem like an comparison much at all, and I’m having trouble with the way the book is labeling and translating it.
Here’s the sentence with the translation:
**新しい車を買うより仕方がありません。
There’s no other way than to buy a new car.**
To me it just seems that they took the dictionary definition of より “than” and just used that for their translation. Is this a nuanced sort of comparison that I’m not understanding that goes beyond the English translation? I’m having trouble wrapping my head around how this sentences より is used for comparison. Also I would like to note that that the テレビを見るより... example using “Rather” in its translation may be throwing me off a bit. [image]

Comment: Because no one's answering, try [#3](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A/#jn-228484).

Comment: Thank you. So if I’m understanding correctly this より is more there to emphasize the negatives rather than to be an comparison like in the example: 狭いが、ここで寝るよりしかたがない 
It’s narrow but it cant be helped but to sleep here (is this sounding correct perhaps?)